# What am I doing wrong with this background image?

Tags: html, css

I am using a separate background image on this website than the one applied first. The background image I want to use in the header area of the page is not showing even though I triple checked for the link to the image being correct. Is there anything interfering with the image's ability to show up?

```css
body, html {
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  
}

body {
  background-image: url("../Images/firepit2.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:visited {
  
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:active {
  
}

#Logo {
  font-size: 3em;
  background-color: #064501; /* Dark Woodrow Green */
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#Quote {
  background-color: #064501;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;  
}

#HeaderText {
  background-image: url("Images/GrassBackground.jpg");
}

#Navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  padding: 10px;
}

#Navigation li {
  display: inline; 
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#Navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

#Wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 90px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

#Greeting {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#Wrapper p {
  line-height: 1.1em; 
  margin-top: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: #064501; /* Dark Woodrow Green */
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #064501;
}

footer p {
  float: left; 
}

footer ul {
  float: right; 
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline;
}

footer::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

#Copyright {
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#Contact {
  margin-right: 25px; 
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#Contact li {
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Woodrow Lawn and Turf</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!--
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
-->
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/index.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<!-- DEVELOPER NOTES -->
  <!--

    - Keywords and description meta are still subject to change by the client.
    - Make sure to add correct target attributes and file paths to the nav links.
    - All images used in this mockup are subject to copyright currently.
    - Make sure to add alternate font families to the font-family style. (2 only)
    - Viewport scale commented currently.

  -->
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="HeaderText">
      <h1 id="Logo">Woodrow Lawn and Turf</h1>
      <p id="Quote"><i>"Turf turf lawn turf turf lawn"</i></p>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="Navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Lawn Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Dirt Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Flower Bed Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Patio Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Firepit Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Commercial and Business Stuff</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="Wrapper">
    <h1 id="Greeting">Welcome!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
    <footer>
      <p id="Copyright">&copy; Copyright Woodrow Lawn and Turf LLC 2017</p>
      <ul id="Contact">
        <li>Contact:</li>
        <li><a href="tel:+1-999-999-9999">(999)999-9999</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="mailto:stuffcompany@comp.net">stuffcompany@comp.net</a></li>      
      </ul>
    </footer>
  

 

 
</body>
  
  
  









</html>
```

Comment: Your body background is up a directory from your css (../) but your header image is in the same directory?

Comment: This depends on the browser you're using, but on Chrome: right click -> inspect -> console. See if there are any errors there relating to the image.

Comment: the background color on `#Logo` and `#Quote` is covering it. Remove those background color properties.

Comment: Please share the full path of the image and the css file in which this body properties are set. I am sure that your issue is with the url not resolving to the correct path.

Comment: Okay, so I commented the background colors out in the CSS file, but still the background image will not show. What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the header container has background colors which covers the image

```css
body, html {
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  
}

body {
  background-image: url("../Images/firepit2.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:visited {
  
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:active {
  
}

#Logo {
  font-size: 3em;
 /** background-color: #064501; /* Dark Woodrow Green * this overrides your background image*/
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#Quote {
  /**background-color: #064501;** this overrides your background image*/
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;  
}

#HeaderText {
  background-image: url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png");
}

#Navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  padding: 10px;
}

#Navigation li {
  display: inline; 
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#Navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

#Wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 90px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

#Greeting {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#Wrapper p {
  line-height: 1.1em; 
  margin-top: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: #064501; /* Dark Woodrow Green */
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #064501;
}

footer p {
  float: left; 
}

footer ul {
  float: right; 
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline;
}

footer::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

#Copyright {
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#Contact {
  margin-right: 25px; 
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#Contact li {
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Woodrow Lawn and Turf</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!--
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
-->
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/index.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<!-- DEVELOPER NOTES -->
  <!--

    - Keywords and description meta are still subject to change by the client.
    - Make sure to add correct target attributes and file paths to the nav links.
    - All images used in this mockup are subject to copyright currently.
    - Make sure to add alternate font families to the font-family style. (2 only)
    - Viewport scale commented currently.

  -->
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="HeaderText">
      <h1 id="Logo">Woodrow Lawn and Turf</h1>
      <p id="Quote"><i>"Turf turf lawn turf turf lawn"</i></p>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="Navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Lawn Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Dirt Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Flower Bed Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Patio Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Firepit Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Commercial and Business Stuff</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="Wrapper">
    <h1 id="Greeting">Welcome!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
    <footer>
      <p id="Copyright">&copy; Copyright Woodrow Lawn and Turf LLC 2017</p>
      <ul id="Contact">
        <li>Contact:</li>
        <li><a href="tel:+1-999-999-9999">(999)999-9999</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="mailto:stuffcompany@comp.net">stuffcompany@comp.net</a></li>      
      </ul>
    </footer>
  

 

 
</body>
  
  
  









</html>
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but the background image still will not show. What now? Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Try to hide or delete the h1 and p tag on the header image container to see if the image shows. Also when you inspect the #headerText container. right click on the the image link and click open in new tab. to be sure its is loading the image

Comment: Inspected the container in dev tools and it the image doesn't appear to exist. That must mean there is a problem with the file path correct?

Comment: Just tried to add the image to a random spot in the page and it showed. That means that the file path is correct and there is no background to cover the background image. What else could I possibly try to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Wow end my life now. For almost an hour I have been trying to fix this problem and I forgot to add 2 periods before the slash in the URL for the background image in my folder...